# using typedef in advance

Tags: c++, typedef

I have looked in winsock2.h, and I find that, it confuse me alot:

```
  typedef SOCKET (WSAAPI *LPFN_ACCEPT)(SOCKET s,struct sockaddr *addr,int *addrlen);

  typedef int (WSAAPI *LPFN_BIND)(SOCKET s,const struct sockaddr *name,int namelen);

  typedef int (WSAAPI *LPFN_CLOSESOCKET)(SOCKET s);

  typedef int (WSAAPI *LPFN_CONNECT)(SOCKET s,const struct sockaddr *name,int namelen);

  typedef int (WSAAPI *LPFN_IOCTLSOCKET)(SOCKET s,__LONG32 cmd,u_long *argp);

  typedef int (WSAAPI *LPFN_GETPEERNAME)(SOCKET s,struct sockaddr *name,int *namelen);
```

anyone can explain of this situation of using typedef? It would be so appriciate :)

Comment: I assume `WSAAPI` is yet another Windows/VS extension (or a macro expanding to one). Otherwise, it's just using typedef to assign names to five function pointer types returning `int`, and to one function function pointer type returning `SOCKET`

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a typedef for a function pointer. For example: `typedef SOCKET (WSAAPI *LPFN_ACCEPT)(SOCKET s,struct sockaddr *addr,int *addrlen);` declares a function called `LPFN_ACCEPT` which takes a `SOCKET s`, `struct sockaddr *addr`, and an `int *addrlen` as arguments and returns a `SOCKET`. The `WSAAPI` declares the calling convention for this function pointer.

Comment: thanks you, for the WSAAPI explanation,